# Simpler way to create multiple appends for a custom numpad

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

is there a faster/simpler way to make this:? I'm creating a numpad in my Android App which I use 10 buttons for and a delete button. Right now I'm doing it like this but like this it's gonna take a lot of code.

```
    num0.setOnClickListener(){
        editTextNumberPassword.append("0")
    }
    num1.setOnClickListener(){
        editTextNumberPassword.append("1")
    }
    num2.setOnClickListener(){
        editTextNumberPassword.append("3")
    }
```

Comment: By using tag on button and same listener which takes clicked button's tag and append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all views into a list and then use the index:

```kotlin
listOf(num0, num1, num2)
    .withIndex()
    .forEach { (index, view) ->
        view.setOnClickListener { editTextNumberPassword.append("$index") }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the setOnClickListener  isn't recognized. Edit: the view and index need to be swapped, so index.setOnClickListener and $view. Like this it works! Also one more question, how do I make a delete button that deletes 1 int at a time?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. Just had to swap the order of the parameter names :)

To delete the last character you'd like to get the text value and then do `string.take(length - 1)` `if length is > 0`

Comment: What is the length in .take? It isn't recognized

Comment: Stop copy-pasting code and put some thought into where you'd have to get the length from :) I remind you you're trying to take the last character of some _value_ of some _text_ field…

Comment: I have it working using substring like this: `editTextNumberPassword.setText(edit.substring(0,input - 1))`

Comment: `String.take` does the exact same. It takes the first `N` chars from a string. So if you want to get rid of the last one `String.length - 1`. I am glad you could figure that one out on your own! Congratulations!!